# Passing Variables/Arguments to Files in Phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am currently developing a phonegap application, it is entirely dynamic, so it pulls data from an exposed JSON api, some of the data is very specific, for example /page.html/25/, where 25 would be the id of the page I need to get. My question is, what is the right way to pass the data, and the right way to retrieve this data on the page it is passed to?

Comment: Is /page.html/25 the data coming from the service? Or are you talking about linking to a local (to your PG app) page called page.html and passing '25' in the URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you're requesting `JSON` data from an API then you're probably initiating that AJAX request yourself, in which case I would just use the `data`option of the `$.ajax()` method to pass your id:

```
$.ajax({
    url  : "http://www.someurl.com/",
    type : "post",
    data : { id : 25 },
    ...
});
```

Or if you must use the `/page.html/25/` syntax then you can just concoct your URL:

```
$.ajax({
    url  : "http://www.someurl.com/page.html/25/",
    ...
});
```

Comment: yeah for example, I have index.html which gets a bunch of objects from the API and generates page.html/{object_id}/, and when you go to page.html is retrieves specific object data based on the ID passed to it.